# Convert Swift Dictionary With Enum Value To NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift

If I have a dictionary with the type `Dictionary<String, MyEnum>`, I cannot figure out how to convert it to an NSDictionary so I can serialiaze it to JSON via `NSJSONSerialize.dataWithJSONObject`.

The compiler tells me that "`Dictionary<String, MyEnum> is not convertible to NSDictionary`". Do I need to create a new dictionary with the string values of the enum a la

```
var newDict = Dictionary<String, String> (or <String, AnyObject>);
for (key, val) in oldDict {
    newDict[key] = val;
}
```

or is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSJSONSerialize` and friends can only deal with small subset of NSObject children (NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, and NSNull) that correspond to the JSON native data types.  In addition, a Dictionary can only be converted to an NSDictionary if both the key and value are NSObject or inherently convertible to NSObject (String and numeric types).

In order to serialize your Dictionary you'll need to convert the Enum to one of those NSJSONSerialize data-types, similar to your example:

```
enum MyEnum : String {
    case one = "one"
    case two = "two"
}

let dict = ["one":MyEnum.one, "two":MyEnum.two]

var newDict = Dictionary<String, String>()
for (key, val) in dict {
    newDict[key] = val.rawValue
}

let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(newDict, options: .allZeros, error: nil)
```

As an alternative, since this kind of manipulation is fairly common, you might want to consider adding this category to Dictionary, which gives it a convenient `map` function:

```
extension Dictionary {
    init(_ pairs: [Element]) {
        self.init()
        for (k, v) in pairs {
            self[k] = v
        }
    }

    func map<K: Hashable, V>(transform: Element -> (K, V)) -> [K: V] {
        return Dictionary<K, V>(Swift.map(self, transform))
    }
}
```

Once that's done, the conversion is simply:

```
let mapped = dict.map { (key, value) in (key, value.rawValue) }
```

Comment: Yeah, I suspected this was the case. I am very much looking forward to native Swift methods to deal with JSON, because if this is indeed the solution, I might as well just not work with enums when dealing with JSON heavy code.

Comment: For more general usage, I tend to wrap NSJSONSerialization in functionality that depends on a JSONSerializable protocol that includes a `convertToJson` object that converts the object to a JSONSerializable form.  Then simple enums like you're using here can just implement that method as `return rawValue`

Comment: Ah interesting. That would be a good way to do this generally. I just have this one instance of this being a problem however, so I will probably just get rid of the enum in my project. I was not doing much with it anyway and was just in the habit of using an enum from my Java days. Thanks for the pointer though.

Answer (score 0):

```
public protocol EnumCollection: Hashable {
    static func cases() -> AnySequence<Self>
    static var allValues: [Self] { get }
}

public extension EnumCollection {

    public static func cases() -> AnySequence<Self> {
        return AnySequence { () -> AnyIterator<Self> in
            var raw = 0
            return AnyIterator {
                let current: Self = withUnsafePointer(to: &raw) { $0.withMemoryRebound(to: self, capacity: 1) { $0.pointee } }
                guard current.hashValue == raw else {
                    return nil
                }
                raw += 1
                return current
            }
        }
    }

    public static var allValues: [Self] {
        return Array(self.cases())
    }
}

public enum ScreenName: String, EnumCollection
{
    case HomeView = "Home View"
    case SignUpViewController = "Domain Validate View"

    var name: String {
        get { return String(describing: self) }
    }
    var description: String {
        get { return String (self.rawValue) }
    }

    // a dictionary mapping the raw values to the values
    static var allValuesDictionary: [String : String]{
        var values = [String : String]()

        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: ScreenName.allValues)
        for (_, v) in mirror.children{
            guard let screenName = v as? ScreenName else{continue}
            values[screenName.name] = screenName.description
        }
        return values
    }
}
```

Now you can call the method `allValuesDictionary` will return the dictionary with `<key, value> = <case, rawValue>`

```
<HomeView, "Home View">, <SignUpViewController, "Domain Validate View">
```