# Xcode : Compiler error Dictionary <key, value > is not convertible to hashable

Tags: ios, xcode, dictionary, compiler-errors

I'm making an app in Xcode using Swift and the build fails even though there seem to be no errors in the code. I do, however, get this error:

> Compiler error Dictionary <>key, value <> is not convertible to hashable.

How can I fix this? I have searched this but found nothing helpful.

Comment: Are you using JSON? Post the code where you use the Dictionary! Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916092/convert-swift-dictionary-with-enum-value-to-nsdictionary !

Comment: Swift or Objective-C, edit the question and add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Would you mind adding some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ObjectiveC:
An `NSDictionary` key must conform to the `NSCopying` protocol. If the key is a custom object add the code to make it conform.

Swift:
All of a dictionary's keys must be compatible with its key type (Key).

From [The Swift Programming Language - Dictionary Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html):

> The key type of a dictionary must conform to the Swift standard library Hashable protocol.

From Coding Explorer BLog:

> The built in Swift types like Int, Double, and String are hashable.